# Why is the loop terminating at the first successful find?

Tags: excel, vba

Please look at the code below, i'm very new at this and don't understand why i got an email for "8" only .

```
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

    Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For i = 2 To 11
' i am scrolling through excel rows in the[enter image description here][1]

    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "OKAY" Then


    olmail.To = "bla.bla@mailmac.net"
    olmail.Subject = "NEW TRIAL"
    olmail.Body = " please transfer order  " & 
    Cells(i, 1).Value & "  to next month"
    olmail.send
    End If
    Next i
```

[image]

Comment: You created and sent your 1 mail item that you created (here: `Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)`). For each email you'll have to create a new mail item.

Comment: Note that you have a mix of early and late binding, e.g. early: `Dim olapp As Outlook.Application`, and late: `Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")`. Might be worth being consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a new email each time, like so:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

    Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem

    For i = 2 To 11

        If Cells(i, 4).Value = "OKAY" Then

            'Create new email
            Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            olmail.To = "bla.bla@mailmac.net"
            olmail.Subject = "NEW TRIAL"
            olmail.Body = " please transfer order  " & Cells(i, 1).Value & "  to next month"
            olmail.send

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!